# Running JBehave with Junit 5 Jupiter

Tags: java, junit, jbehave

I'm trying to get some JUnit 4 based JBehave tests running on JUnit 5. In my project I have a single test class for all stories `JBehaveTest`.

When I run it as a JUnit 5 test JUnit doesn't see any tests. I modified the `@Test` annotations to their Jupiter equivalents, I changed the `assertTrue` and `assertFalse` to their equivalents, etc.

The JUnit 4 test is annotated with a `@RunWith` annotation, which in JUnit 5 should be a `@ExtendWith` annotation if I understood correctly. Unfortunately `JBehave` is not a JUnit 5 extension, so it won't compile.

Can JBehave be used with JUnit 5, and if so, how?

```
@RunWith(AnnotatedEmbedderRunner.class)
@UsingEmbedder(embedder = Embedder.class, verboseFailures = true,  ignoreFailureInStories = false, generateViewAfterStories = true)
public class JBehaveTest implements Embeddable {
private Embedder embedder;
private DotStoryReporter dot = new DotStoryReporter();
private Stage primaryStage;

@Before
public void createStage() throws TimeoutException {
    Locale locale = new Locale("fa", "IR");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    primaryStage = FxToolkit.registerPrimaryStage();
}

@Override
@Test
public void run() throws Throwable {
    embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(new StoryFinder().findPaths("src/test/resources", Collections.singletonList("**/*.story"), Collections.<String>emptyList()));
}

@Override
public void useEmbedder(Embedder embedder) {
    this.embedder = embedder;
    MostUsefulConfiguration configuration = new MostUsefulConfiguration();
    Steps steps = new Steps();
    configuration.useStoryReporterBuilder(
            new StoryReporterBuilder()
                    .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(JBehaveTest.class))
                    .withDefaultFormats()
                    .withReporters(dot, new MyStoryReporter(new File("test"), steps))
                    .withFormats(Format.HTML, Format.TXT)
                    .withFailureTrace(true)
                    .withFailureTraceCompression(false));
    configuration.useStepdocReporter(new DetailedStepReporter());

    embedder.useStepsFactory(new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration, steps));
    embedder.useConfiguration(configuration);
}
```

The Gradle test dependencies are:

```
testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.3'
testRuntime 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0'
testRuntime 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.2.0'
testCompile 'org.testfx:testfx-core:4.0.+'
testCompile 'org.testfx:testfx-junit5:4.0.+'
testCompile 'org.jbehave:jbehave-core:4.3.2'
testCompile 'de.codecentric:jbehave-junit-runner:1.2.0'
```

Comment: you can run JUnit4-based JBehave tests using JUnit 5 platform, but still there will be old-fashioned JUnit4 (old annotations and etc.). If you are looking for complete support of JUnit 5, it's not available, you may need to file a new JIRA ticket (http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/issue-tracking.html)